# WPF DataGrid binding to property in subclass

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to properly bind a datagrid column with data in a subclass. To clear things up, I've done a little sample which, if resolved, would greatly help in making the code work.

Here are the classes defined:

```
public class SubItem
    {
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }

public class Item
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public SubItem Data { get; set; }
    }
```

I then create an observablecollection as follows:

```
public class IntData : ObservableCollection<Item>
    {
        public IntData() : base()
        {
            Item i = new Item() { Value = 56, Data = new SubItem() { Data = "testdata" } };
            Add(i);
        }
    }
```

And here is my MainWindow code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public IntData Integers { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            Integers = new IntData();

            InitializeComponent();
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = Integers; // This is an important line
        }
    }
```

The XAML code is kept simple:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="12">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Integers" Binding="{Binding Value}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data" Binding="{Binding Data}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

[image]

Running the above, you will notice that the Integers is working as it should but not the Data column.
Any ideas from anyone on how to make that column show the Data property?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can simply override `ToString()` method in `SubItem` class, or define the date column template for that

Comment: You can also bind to a subclass `<DataGridTextColumn Header="Data" Binding="{Binding Data.Data}"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to fix it is to override `ToString()` method in `SubItem` class and return `Data` property

```cs
public class SubItem
{
    public string Data { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Data;
    }
}
```

Another option is update `DataGridTextColumn` binding and use `Data` sub-property of `Data` property from `Item` class (you'll probably need to update a naming:))

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Data" Binding="{Binding Data.Data}"/>
```

More complicated option is to use `DataGridTemplateColumn` and define your own template to represent a data

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Data">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Data.Data}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: @JediMaster when you add a row, you should populate the entire `SubItem` class, not the simple string

Comment: Ah but now I'm getting **System.InvalidOperationException: 'Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.'** when I add a row. Do you have any idea why? I didn't get that error when I was testing using only the Item class without the SubItem class

Comment: I'm adding a row via the Datagrid itself and getting the Two-way path error. Shouldn't it be possible to add a new row using the Datagrid itself?

Comment: @JediMaster I don't think that it'll work on the such way. Please, have a look at my previous comment. If solution isn't working, you can unapprove an answer, but you error is different from what you asking in original question

Comment: Ok I'll try to raise another question about this to see if I can get pointers. Thanks again for your help :)!

Comment: woh! The `DataGridTemplateColumn` with `TextBox` worked great!!!